# Issue with tensor flow during predict function getting this error expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am training a model with this shape of data input data

```
input_data.shape
Out[51]: (3145, 11)
```

and this output_data

```
output_data.shape
Out[53]: (3145,)
```

Then I create an fit the model with this code

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(11,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x = input_data, y = output_data, epochs=10, verbose=1)
model.save(tensor_model)
```

This works as expected and fits and runs.
However when I try to do a prediction with this data with this shape

```
to_be_prdicted.shape
Out[57]: (11,)
```

with this code

```
output = model.predict(x=to_be_prdicted)
```

I get this error

```
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_18' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_17" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_18' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

It errors out and give me a value error message talking about "min_ndim=2, found ndim=1 Full shape received: (None,)".

Here is also the summary of my model if it helps

```
model.summary()
Model: "sequential_18"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_17 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 12        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 12
Trainable params: 12
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have tried adding the input to the model with

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(11,)))
```

As you can see above but the code errors out either way with the same error

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you need to provide the same shape dimension of the prediction dataset(`to_be_predicted`) as per `input_data.shape` dimension which was used to define and train the model.

Here, `input_data` shape has two dimension -  (3145, 11)
Likewise `to_be_predicted.shape` should be in the same dimension.

**For example:**

```
to_be_predicted = np.random.random((23, 11)).astype(np.float32) 
to_be_predicted.shape
```

Output:

```
 (23, 11)
```

Or you can expand the `to_be_predicted` dataset dimension to match with `input_shape` using below code:

```
to_be_predicted = np.random.random((11)).astype(np.float32) 
to_be_predicted.shape # Output: (11,)

import numpy as np
to_be_predicted = np.expand_dims(to_be_prdicted, axis=0)
to_be_predicted.shape
```

Output:

```
(1, 11)
```